# matlab find files according to filenames and extract columns

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a folder with files that have similar name with different number in the file names:

```
P_Coord = 'C:\Coordinates\coor2.dom.txt';'C:\Coordinates\coor3.dom.txt';..etc until 100.
```

I get a number CaseNo  from the list which is equal to one of the numbers in the filename.

I would like to search CaseNo in file name in the folder and when it finds the filename with that number, to extract 2nd and 3 st column values (coordinates) from that file where row.name equal to midday.

For example, CaseNo = 3 needs file 'Coor3.com.txt'. (also it need to avoid file names 38,31,31,33,13 etc)

```
fileCoor = dir('Coor*.com.txt');

for i = 1:numel(fileCoor)
 if (CaseNo = fileCoor(i).name)
```

%I think I need to use regexp for that but not sure how to make it work

```
CaseNo  = regexp (fileCoor(i).name,'Coor(\d*).dom.txt');
```

%extract 2nd and 3rd columns

```
CaseCoor [x][y] = fileCoor (2;midday),(3;midday)
```

I'm not very familiar with Matlab and spent long time to figure out how to implement it. Any help would be much appreciated!

This is how those text files look like(i need to take 2&3 col of row midday):

```
morning  -13.451536  -52.025423  -1.043887
Bd   3.222905    6.761101    -69.551082
...
midday   31.112678   -84.673258  -47.892980
```

thanks,
Mila

Comment: "2nd and 3rd columns" - you mean 2nd and 3rd columns from within the file?  The files have named rows and a set of columns?

Comment: @nkjt yes i have edited above description with the example of text files i have

Comment: You really need to read the MATLAB help on data import, but I'll give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the num2str function?

```
fileName= ['Coor',num2str(CaseNo),'.com.txt');
```

And then compare the variable fileName with all the files in your folder with the function strcmp.

Check the following functions in matlab help if you want more details: num2str, strcmp

Comment: Erratum: I read again your question more precisely. The solution I'm offering is the opposite of what you want to do, sorry (I don't think I deserve the point I just got). In your case, you already get all the files in the folder but want to know which numbers are present. You're right: regexp is the solution. Check the regexp help to find out how you can say "one or more figures with 1 character before and a dot after". At a first guess, the solution you give should work, I'm surprised it doesn't. I'll come up with a more precise answer when I have time if you can't find it yourself.

Comment: regexp above that i use returns empty cell. caseNo = [].. i think this is closest regexp i could find that would match description.

Comment: mil: I just noticed that sometimes you use 'c', sometimes 'C', sometimes 'dom' and sometimes 'com'. I tried your code and it seems to work if you're consistent.

Comment: When I use CaseNo  = regexp (P_Coord(i).name,'Coor(\d*).dom.txt');. Im wondering does it look for a given number CaseNo in the filename part(\d*)? can you post the code that works for you please where it extract columns from the files? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your files have a set naming system, e.g. "coor2.dom.txt", you can simply use `sprintf` to create the filename and `exist` to check if it's there:

```
for n = 1:100
    fname = sprintf('coor%d.dom.txt',n);
    if exist(fname)          
        % then do stuff with this file       
    end
end
```

(Note: you can add the full path to the `sprintf` command; if you don't, `exist` will only look on the MATLAB path).

There are a few ways you could read in that data once you have the filename. It depends on some aspects of your data you haven't mentioned (is row 'midday' always at same position in the file, do all the files contain a row 'midday', are the row contents consistent) on which is the best way of tackling it.

For example:

You could open the file using `fopen`, use `fgetl` to read individual lines in until you find one that starts `midday`, then extract those values out of the line.  This is (imo) inelegant but will work on a wide range of data formats e.g. you can use this even if the row contents are inconsistent.

Otherwise, if all rows contain one string and three numbers as you show in your example, and the file is not overly large, my preference would be to use `textscan` with an appropriate format string (e.g. `'%s%f%f%f'`) to pull the whole file in, check the first column for the string 'midday' (using `strfind`, `strcmp`, etc) to find the right row, then extract the appropriate data from columns 2 and 3.

If you have a recent version of MATLAB, `readtable` would also be an option and can handle row names automatically.

Comment: The file is there. I read CaseNo. Given a CaseNo = 3  I need to find a file 'Coor3.com.txt'. Given CaseNo = 38 I need file 'Coor38.com.txt'. I am not sure sprintf will consider it that is why i thought I could use regexp.

Comment: How to check that 'CaseNo' is in filename 'Coor(\d*)',CaseNo should be equal to \d*: CaseNo = regexp (P_Coord(i).name,'Coor(\d*).dom.txt');

Comment: All I'm suggesting is that you use `sprintf` to make up the appropriate filename for each case number, and then check if it exists, rather than trying to strip the case numbers out of the files.  I don't even get why you're trying to use `regexp` here.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was wrong, so here's what I did:

```
>>P_Coord = 'C:\Coordinates\coor2212.dom.txt'
```

You want to get only the number from this string, right?

```
>>CaseNo  = regexp (P_Coord,'\d+','match')
CaseNo =
     '2212'
```

I get the answer you want. If you happen to have another number in your string (e.g 'C:\Coordinates2\coor2212.dom.txt', you'll have to refine your search.

Concerning getting the rows with only morning, you could also import your files in tables (if you have a recent version of matlab): http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/table.html

```
T = readtable(P_Coord,'ReadRowNames','true','Delimiter','\t') % Your delimiters are tabs, right? 
%It will also consider first column as "row names"
MorningData = T({'morning'},2:3); %get data from column 2 and 3 for rows called "morning"
```

This should work :)

Comment: Sorry I do not think i have explained clearly what I need. I feed into my Matlab A LIST of text files. Not just one. P_Coor was just given to explain.  fileCoor = dir('Coor*.com.txt'); Then i get a number from the system. I need to go through the LIST of files. Find the file with the Given Number in the filename. And extract 2,3 col-s from it. You just load the file I'm looking for already in your answer. i'm a newbie so I do not really get your answer.

Comment: Yes you did clearly explain. But I was not going to build up a list of random names and numbers. I don't think the step from a single string to a list of string is very complex. Using a for-loop and a cell of strings (cell of strings where you saved all the files from your coordinates folder).

Comment: Oh I guess I need to finish my explanation. Then you compare "CaseNo" you get from regexp to the case number you want to import it. If it's the same, you import it. The help from matlab is pretty good, the only hard part is to know what exists and what are the possibilities.

Comment: I get error when I try your code above: >> T = readtable(P_Coord,'ReadRowNames','true','Delimiter','')
Undefined function 'readtable' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: Yes, tables are available only in Matlab 2013+ versions. If you don't have it, I guess you should import in other matlab structures. Type "which table" to see if you have that.

Comment: Thanks for the response since im using matlab2013a version i cannot use readtable and hence your answer.

Comment: Oh ok sorry. I would advise you to import in cells then, it requires a bit more work though. check the cellfun function and how you can compare in each cell the string in it to the string "morning".